# Java(Android): Convert signed byte to int

Tags: java, android

I am writing an Android App which will read data from another device, the data received is an byte array like:

> byte[] data = {X,X,X,X,H,H,X,X};

The HH above is a ASCII hex representation of a signed byte. For example "0C" represent a value 12, "FB" represent value -5, "FF" is -1

I receive the HH from the data by:

```
byte[] HH_array = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, 4, 6);
```

And then change it to String:

```
String HH_str = new String(HH_array);
```

To get the HH value:

```
int HH_int = (Integer.parseInt(HH_str, 16));
```

However, here the integer value become a positive number even the original HH is negative.

I want to ask how can I change the signed byte received in the data array HH_array, and store it to a signed int?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer my question, I have to add the following code at the end:

```
if((HH_int &0x80) > 0) {
    HH_int = -(0x80-(HH_int &0x7f));
}
```

Firstly it compare the 8th bit to check whether it is a negative number. Then it convert to the value in 2's complemnt.

Thank you to a member who answered an "almost correct" answer which gave me hint to get what I want. Unfortunately he removed his answer and I forgot his name.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
byte b = 0xFF;
int i = (int)(sbyte)b;
```